# How to get the proxy node in openstack swift cluster?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I know the command `swift-ring-builder /etc/swift/object.builder` can get all storage nodes in a swift cluster. Now I want to know if there are any commands like it to get the proxy nodes in the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of storage nodes **MUST** be accessible for all nodes in the cluster.

However, swift is agnostic about the list of proxies it has, so there is no command like that.

One suggestion, if you really need this information, would be to look at the storage nodes logs and find out the ips doing the requests. This way you can discover some or all  proxies. **However** this method is **totally imprecise**.

Answer (score 1):

Every controller node itself acts as a proxy server first.The requests hit the proxy-server code in the controller node which resolves functions and methods to be called and acts upon.